# Using the coefficients from regression models that use group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I run the following code to generate regression models

```
library (dplyr)
fitted_models <- df %>% 
  group_by(sic, fyear) %>% 
  do (model = lm (TACCdTA ~  Inverse_TA + DeL_RevRec + PPEdTA , data = .))
```

Then to get the coefficients for each sic and fyear, I run the following code

```
library(broom)
fitted_models %>% tidy(model)
```

I got coefficients for each **sic** for each **fyear**.

Now my question is - under each **sic** for each **fyear**, there are many observations (e.g., 1000 observations) - how can I calculate the fitted value for each observation under each **sic** and **fyear** by using the coefficients that the model(s) generated above.

Another small question - for my first code in which I run the model, how can I ensure that the model(s) is(are) run only for the cases in which each **sic** and **fyear** combination (sic-fyear) has at least 10 observations.

Comment: To make sure there are at least 10 observations maybe `filter(n() >= 10)` right after `group_by`.

Comment: See `?broom::augment` for the 1st question, for the 2nd you may use `filter` as Rui suggested.

Comment: @A.Suliman if I run `fitted_models %>% augment(model)` then I got predicted value for each sic and fyear, but I want predicted value for each observation under sic-fyear combination. Thanks

Comment: @Sharif sorry but I didn't understand the difference between _predicted value for each sic and fyear_ and _predicted value for each observation under sic-fyear combination_, maybe you need to provide a reproducible example using `mtcars` along with your expected output.

Comment: @A.Suliman I got it correct. `mod <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%    
  do(model = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=.)) ` and `mod %>% tidy(model)`  To get the predicted for each obs. I run these codes `r <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(augment(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=.)))` Then I got the expected results.